# Building SSAS Cubes Manually without a Wizard

Tags: ssas, cube, olap-cube, ssas-2008

i searched online and could find only building cubes with Cube Wizard only.Does any of you have some documentation or articles related to cubes building manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had close to zero knowledge of SSAS at my last company. After reading the book linked below, I built a Production Sales Order Cube in less than 8 weeks containing over 200 million rows of data that could be updated weekly in less than an hour. This book shows you how to do everything every step of the way, recommending best practices and pitfalls to avoid. I would highly recommend it.

[http://www.amazon.com/Expert-Development-Microsoft-Analysis-Services/dp/1847197221/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1425999411&sr=8-8&keywords=microsoft+ssas](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847197221)